# displaying more than 1 div horizontally and viewing them using a horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to display a number of div (boxes) horizontally inside of a fixed-width div. I would like to use a horizontal scroll bar to display the divs all of which do not fit inside the parent div.

However, the divs are displaying vertically, rather than horizontally. Is there a way to force them to display side-by-side?  and also view them using horizontal scroll bar. i've posted the coding below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Slide </title>
<style type="text/css">
.total
{
height:350px;
width:75%;
border:1px solid black;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:15%;
}
.slidepanel
{
border:1px solid purple;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
.slideleft
{
border:1px solid green;
width:5%;
height:10%; 
margin-left:5%;
float:left;
text-align:center;
//padding-top:1%;
}
.slideright
{
//padding-top:1%;
border:1px solid green;
width:5%;
height:10%; 
margin-left:80%;
float:left;
text-align:center;
}
.box
{
border:1px solid red;
width:100%;
height:100%;
float:left;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="total">
<div class="slidepanel">
<button class="slideleft">
 <<
</button>
<button class="slideright">
 >>
 </button>
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by putting a wrapper around them. Like this http://dabblet.com/gist/2787474

Answer (score 1):

You've given `.box` width 100%, so it will always take the width of the full page, hence there will be no space left to put the other boxes beside it. Make it less wide and it'll work.

http://jsfiddle.net/JDeaZ/

Comment: i've put 100% of the width of the div class="slidepanel", it will not take the entire page.. pls guide me what has to be done

Comment: @TasneemFathima I should have been more clear. `width: 100%` will have it take the full width of its container. In this case, `.slidepanel` is contained by `.total`, which has only a width of 75%. So, you need to change the width of `.total` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just like @RobinJ suggested, give the box a specific width.

Also I would get rid of the margin: auto; since this will center your div. you can use use for instance margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; to give it some spacing on the left and right side of you div.

This would be how my code would look:

```
.box{
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 300px; /*fill in your desired width*/
    height: 300px; /*fill in your desired height*/
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

cool just some tips and an easy way of doing it, work with the same data values as much as possible, % will sometimes throw elements around in IE, px is good, 1200px for a width is good over a variety of screen sizes. here is how i would do it.

HTML

```
<div id="box_wrapper">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

the css

```
#box_wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: /*top and bottom*/5px auto/*left and right*/; /*this will keep it centred*/
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 398px;
}
```

its good to specify specific px, but good job on the border technique it helps with positioning and getting the right size you want so just experiment with width.

you could do something fancy and make the overflow-x hidden and then

```
#box_wrapper:hover {
 overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

hope that helps :D